# jQuery Tabs change on specific div id inside tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

I have 5 tabs lined up next to each other on the page and each tab uses the href to change tabs. I basically have a div with an image map inside one of the tabs with and an id and when I hover over the div inside the tab it just doesn't change to that tab, however if I hover over the section of the tab where the div is not there it happily changes to the hovered tab.

So I've selected the id of the div inside the tab and used the hover function then made a variable and selected the id of the tab that I'm currently on which returns 4 when I've alerted out the variable so I know that section works, but still it doesn't change to the tab when I hover over the div with the image map inside.

Here is the section of jQuery where I attempt to change to that tab when hovered over the div inside.

```
$('ul#featureList li#unbeatableDealsLi #carsVansNearlyNew').hover(function(){
   var index = $('#featureContainer ul#featureList li#unbeatableDealsLi [href="#unbeatableDeals"]').parent().index();
   $('#featureContainer ul#featureList li#unbeatableDealsLi [href="#unbeatableDeals"]').tabs('option', 'selected', index);
});
```

Comment: Can you make a small working sample on http://jsfiddle.net?  Strip out everything you can, cut the number of tabs down, rename the classes, etc.  The goal is to demonstrate the problem with as few chars as possible.

Comment: We need to see your markup, to help you, also if you have a live example it could be better to see the problem